# Extracting user entry from text box and storing it in a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
// text Box
        &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3"  runat="server" BackColor="Silver" 
            BorderColor="Silver" ontextchanged="TextBox3_TextChanged" 
            style="margin-left: 6px" Width="154px"></asp:TextBox>

// Submit button
        &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" BackColor="Silver" 
            onClientclick='store_memID()' style="margin-left: 20px" Text="Submit" 
            Width="102px" Font-Bold="True" Height="28px" />


    <script type = "text/javascript">
        // Function to caputure client-input- Member_ID.
        function store_memID() {

            var mem_ID = document.getElementById('TextBox3').value;


            return confirm('TimeLine is displayed for: ' + mem_ID);
        }

    </script>
```

When I run the code and enter a value into the text box and then press the submit button:-
"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined".

Else, if I remove the '.value' :-

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    // Function to caputure client-input- Member_ID.
    function store_memID() {

        var mem_ID = document.getElementById('TextBox3');


        return confirm('TimeLine is displayed for: ' + mem_ID);
    }

</script>
```

and then run the program, enter value in text box and press submit then i get :-

"TimeLine is displayed for: Null"

I have been looking into solving this problem. not sure whats going wrong...

***Edit (fix):- Server Side ID for my text box is 'TextBox3' but this doesn't necessarily match up with the client side ID. 
to get Client Side ID:- '<%=TextBox3.ClientID%>'***

Comment: There is no element named 'TextBox3'. Can you look at the page in a debugger and see how the asp:TextBox element gets rendered into raw HTML?

Comment: isn't my textbox named 'TextBox3' ?? 
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3"....>

Comment: Could you open your page in a browser to see the rendered HTML code and paste that here as well? That's the important part for JS.

Comment: @user1683846 Server-side, yes. Client-side, not always. If you're using any "containers," such as `MasterPage`s, `<asp:UpdatePanel />`, data-bound controls, etc., it may be munged to describe its containment and ensure uniqueness: `id="ctl00$ContentName$TextBox3"`. ASP.NET 4.0 added the [`ClientIDMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) property to offer some control over this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I wrote asp forms but it is likely that the id on the client side (in your browser) is not what you think it is. This is/was one of the major pitfalls of web forms in my mind (This may have been made simpler in version 4.0, you'll have to check that). You could use a css class (and use jQuery or similar to find your element) or inject the client side id into the java script e.g.;

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    // Function to caputure client-input- Member_ID.
    function store_memID() {
        var mem_ID = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox3.ClientID%>').value;
        return confirm('TimeLine is displayed for: ' + mem_ID);
    }
</script>
```

**UPDATE: fixed case error in ClientID as pointed out in comments**

Comment: I got an error:-

 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'ClientId' and no extension method 'ClientId' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @user1683846 Try `ClientID` (case-sensitive).

Comment: that worked. thanks. but this is lame. why does my page refer to the button as TextBox3.. when this might not be the actual ID on the client side ??

Answer (score 1):

You are using asp Text Boxes which are mostly used for server side code. The ID you place in the tag is not guaranteed to match the ID of the element rendered.

You will need to inspect your html in the browser to find the rendered ids. (Likely will look something like: ct100_TextBox3) and use that instead. Or, if you are not doing any server side coding, it would probably be best to convert your text boxes to `<input />` fields, or `<textarea />`.